# Java Apache Commons: MultivariateNormalMixtureExpectationMaximization vs. R Mixtools

Tags: r, java

In R I can use 
    **normalmixEM(data,k=2)** from the Mixtools package
in order to fit two normal distributions to the provided data.

I need to do the same in Java and found [Apache Common Maths MultivariateNormalMixtureExpectationMaximization](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/fitting/MultivariateNormalMixtureExpectationMaximization.html). But the constructor requires a 2-dimensional array, but as in R I only have 1-dimensional data vector.

So why is there a two-dimensional vector required? Or am I looking at the wrong library?

Comment: Note that the function you're looking at is for fitting *Multivariate* normal mixtures.  So you need at least two dimensions for your data structure - 1 to account for the number of observations and another to account for the fact that each observation is a vector.

Comment: Ok, then I might be looking the function. I have only a 1-dim vector of observation and I want to find out which two normal distributions (and their parameters) fit best. As mentioned with normalmixEM(data,k=2) I can do this in R.